# ASP.NET MVC - Passing JSON DateTime to controller not mapping to controller parameters

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am using a jQuery calendar to display events, which is designed to pull data from the server.
On innit the calendar fires off a AJAX request to get an array of events objects (json encoded).
All good so far.
However, this request includes a JSON encoded date and time (at leats my implimentation does).
The code looks like this:

```
data: function (start, end, callback) {
        $.post('/planner/GetPlannerEvents', { test: "test", start: JSON.stringify(start), end: JSON.stringify(end) }, function (result) { callback(result); });
    }
```

The declaration for the GetPlannerEvents controller method looks like this:

```
public ActionResult GetPlannerEvents(DateTime start, DateTime end)
```

The problem is that asp.net mvc 2 cannot seem to automatically parse the json encoded datetime and as such complains that the start and end values are null.

Is there another method I should be using to pass the javascript dates to the server so that they may be parsed correctly?

Thanks,

Comment: Is there any reason you are using JSON.stringify? What are the values prior to that call?

Comment: regular javascript dates. I think the demo I was looking at used JSON.stringify, but really I suppose there is no real reason to use it.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You shouldn't be JSON encoding the dates with `stringify` because the default model binder doesn't expect JSON. Try this:

```
$.post('/planner/GetPlannerEvents', { start: start.toUTCString(), 
    end: end.toUTCString() }, function (result) {
    callback(result); 
});
```

Comment: Again Darin, you make my day!

Comment: May be worth noting the controller expects a string parameter and not a DateTime.

Comment: I wish this answer had more votes. Kinda difficult to dig in the pile of passing date to MVC controller questions. Can't believe toUTCString() was the answer. Props!

Comment: Only problem I've found with this is if you are in west of GMT such as -4 then .toUTCString() produces a day one day behind what the user chose in the date picker.  I.e. 1/3/2013 00:00:00 -4 GMT becomes 1/2/2013 20:00:00 UTC.  My inelegant hack is `someDate = new Date(someDate.getTime() + someDate.getTimezoneOffset()*60000);`  Better suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You also need `.toUTCString().replace('UTC','GMT')` if in IE for MVC to bind successfully.

Answer (score 8):

Try to use `date.toISOString()` to pass data to server. It returns string in ISO8601 format. Also this method can be used to format dates for using in uri.

```
$.post('/planner/GetPlannerEvents', { start: start.toISOString(), 
    end: end.toISOString() }, function (result) {
    callback(result); 
});
```

Why `toISOString` is better than `toUTCString`?
`toUTCString` converts to **human readable string** in the UTC time zone.
`toISOString` converts to **universal ISO format** which allows to resolve issue with regional settings and different formats.

Comment: Totally agree that ISO is much more reliable and consistent than UTC across different machine with different localization settings.

Answer (score 0):

The variations of `date.toString` did not work for me until I added json headers to the post. The resulting code is as follows:

```
var pstData = {
  begDate: date1.toUTCString(),
  endDate :  date2.toUTCString()
};

$.ajax({
  url:'url',
  type:'POST',
  data: JSON.stringify( pstData ),
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
})
```

Answer (score -5):

You need to use return type as 1JsonResult1s instead of 1ActionResult1s

your code goes somthing like this

```
public JasonResult(DateTime start, DateTime end) {
    //some logic
    return Json(); // you can pass any values within Json() with new keyword
}
```